# Deezer Rest API - Add Track to Playlist doesn't work?

Tags: android, rest, deezer

I have an Android application integrated with the deezer rest API, and I need to add a track to a playlist.

My application already has Oauth login flow, when I execute the following request:

```
http://api.deezer.com/user/me?access_token=AJSDH44H5R7SS7SDHDUHFSUDUSUSASDA766
```

Works fine!

**Playlist actions, I trying send this request as:**

**POST**

```
http://api.deezer.com/playlist/777006545/tracks?access_token=AJSDH44H5R7SS7SDHDUHFSUDUSUSASDA766&songs=2312333,12312
```

**GET**

```
http://api.deezer.com/playlist/777006545/tracks?access_token=AJSDH44H5R7SS7SDHDUHFSUDUSUSASDA766&songs=2312333,12312&request_method=post
```

Callback error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user",
    "code": 200
    }
}
```

But the token works for other requests. What's the right way to do this, anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this page?

https://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist#actions ?

It seems you already have found this one:

https://developers.deezer.com/api/actions-post

Here is what I would test:

- POST only.
- Check that your access token has the manage_library permission.
- Check that the owner of the playlist is the same that the user of the access_token.

It worked for me with:

```
http://api.deezer.com/playlist/<playlist_id>/tracks?access_token=<access_token>&request_method=post&songs=<track_id>
```

Comment: The error was here : *Check that the owner of the playlist is the same that the user of the access_token.* Thks